# Concatenating two elements of an array to create a new array element

Tags: java, arrays, string-concatenation

I encountered a problem  with combining array values. I want to combine two values of an array to create a value for another array. Here's my code:

```
String [] candid = {"A","B","C","D","E"};

String [] candidates = new String[candid.length];
        for (int i=0;i<candid.length;i++){
            candidates[i] = candid[i]+","+candid[i+1];
        }
```

But the command `candidates[i] = candid[i]+","+candid[i+1];` is not working.

Comment: That line is concatenating two `String`s. It would be very convenient if you show an input and output sample.

Comment: What does "is not working" stand for? You can click "edit" at the left-bottom of your post to update it any time.

Comment: Please edit and add expected output

Comment: Show the complete code and what actually is going wrong...

Comment: @diyana better to select a correct answer, if any of the answers below are correct!

Answer (score 2):

You might want to declare `candidates` as

```
String [] candidates = new String[candid.length-1];
```

Ps Note: Assuming `candidate` is `candid`

**Update :**

As per OP's Comments `candidates` is initialized to

```
 String [] candidates = new String[candid.length]//Length of candid is used in the 
 question
```

So Initial analysis holds true and code will generate `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` for the last element i.e. `i+1`.

Reason why it happens is you have only 6 elements in the array and when `i is 6 the element` you are trying to access `7 th` element. Array index is -1 of the place I am refereeing. So if length is 5 you are trying to access 6.

Comment: We don't *necessarily* know this is true. `candidate` could be always length 4...

Comment: There is this `String[] candid` so the loop could be *right* (if and only if `candid.length < candidate.length`). The problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @AmitD Actually you have the same answer and it has the same caveat. If `candidate` has length <= 4 there is no issue.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. it should be:

String [] candid = {"A","B","C","D","E"};

String [] candidates = new String[candid.length];
        for (int i=0;i<candid.length;i++){
            candidates[i] = candid[i]+","+candid[i+1];
        }

not working means encounter error.
I want to get output in array candidate = {"A,B","B,C","C,D","D,E"}

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you wanted candidate.length to stand for, but this is what I tried and it seems to work:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] candid = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" };
    String[] candidates = new String[candid.length-1];
    for (int i = 0; i < candid.length-1; i++) {
        candidates[i] = candid[i] + "," + candid[i + 1];
    }
    for (String s : candidates) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Replaced "candidate.length" with "candid.length-1"

The output results in:

> A,B
>   B,C
>   C,D
>   D,E

Comment: I forgot to replace candidate with candid. But yup, your code is work. Thanks for your help.